# Is there a way to make Ninject throw exception immediately if module is loaded twice

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

The code that follows is a simple global.asax. CoreModule is the main module for a suite of applications - and WebAPIModule is a module that inherits off a wrapper class that just wraps standard Ninject modules, but adds a field for dependent modules. If any are listed in that field, it loads them. So if you happen to list CoreModule as a dependency, but have the below code, CoreModule will be loaded twice. This produces transient errors that come and go and are super hard to find reliably. Is there a way to make Ninject throw an exception or fail faster if you load the same Type twice? I haven't seen one, but it would be nice to have a way to fail fast.

```
public class WebApiApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        private void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Load<CoreModule>();
            kernel.Load<WebAPIModule>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a static variable that is set and checked in the `Load()` method of your modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you dynamically loading assemblies?

Ninject will throw an error if you try to load a module that's already been loaded.

You can create an extension method that compares the modules that already exist in the kernel to the modules that you're attempting to load, and only loads the ones that don't already exist.

Copy these extension methods for Assemblies into your own extension method class, along with the following below: [Ninject Assembly Extensions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/5a40fd013ab39b8118ab4c413e5c2ab9414729e9/src/Ninject/Infrastructure/Language/ExtensionsForAssembly.cs)

ExtensionsForKernel.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads modules from specified assemblies that don't already exist in the kernel.
    /// </summary>
    public static void LoadIfNotLoaded(this IKernel kernel, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        var existingModules = kernel.GetModules();
        var newModules = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetNinjectModules())
            .Where(m => !existingModules.Any(em => em.GetType() == m.GetType()));
        kernel.Load(newModules);
    }
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.LoadIfNotLoaded(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    }
```